# Proof for one of the properties of Orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Consider a matrix O, let's assume it has orthonormal basis. If this...
$$o^{T}=o^{-1}$$ is satisfied, then 0 is a orthogonal matrix. But how does one go to prove that the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is equal to its transpose? 
(Basically can someone proof the equation above for me)

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the very definition of an orthogonal matrix you have given?

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes absolutely!

Comment: What is your definition of orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively the definition of an orthogonal matrix, but to see it take a simple example, let $\{o_1,o_2\}$ be some orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $O=[o_1\;o_2]$. Then by definition of the orthonormal basis we know that $OO^{\top}=I_2=OO^{-1}$. Note that $O^{-1}$ is unique and exists due to $\mathrm{det}(O)=1$.

Comment: How does the det(O) =1 relate to the proof. I know that taking the dot product of a one vector to the other in the matrix gives zero... as the definition for the orthogonal matrix. But how does the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is equal to its transpose....can u elaborate a bit more!

Comment: The matrix $O$ should be invertible in the first place, we know this is possible due to $\mathrm{det}(O)=1\neq 0$. Moreover, say $\mathrm{det}(O)=12$, then $\mathrm{det}(OO^{\top})\neq 1 = \mathrm{det}(I_2)$.

Comment: So are u saying is that for orthonormal basis... ^⊤==^−1 with relation to det(O)=1, is a statement that we just accept?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group